# Configure Pip to never install to global environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I want to configure pip so that it will only ever install packages to virtual environments. I there a way to force it so that if ever I accidentally try to install a package to the 'global' environment that it will either deny me or force me through several prompts?

Comment: Doesn't your OS do this by default (as long as you're not running as `root`)?

Comment: @Chris no, by default pip will install to pre-configured system wide python path. No prompts for me.

Comment: Have you considered making the site-packages dir read-only?  (I haven't, so I have no idea about the implications)

Comment: @RockyLi, what OS are you on? It's crazy that you don't need to `sudo` (or whatever OS-specific alternative there is) to do that.

Comment: @Chris mac. granted I `alias pip='pip3'` in my `bashrc` and pip actually only install to local Cellar Python version that I installed with `homebrew`, this python is not system python but it's available from all.

Comment: Not sure if I got this right, but why don't you just use `pipenv`? As you will use only virtual environments, `pipenv` provides you options to automatically install python libraries inside the virtual environment you configured for the project.

Here is the project link: https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: you can configure `pip` global installs to e.g. temp directory by putting `target=/tmp/` under a `[global]` section in your `pip.conf`. This way, the installation will be still performed, but to the temp dir, the "installed" packages wil be not registered anywhere and removed on the next reboot. However, this is not quite what you're asking for, thus not posting that as an answer; just an idea aside.